# Application installed as snap package can't see printer

Tags: kubuntu, snap

Recently I installed latest Inkscape version as snap package and it was all fine until I tried to print something.
Only "Print to file" was listed.
Any advice on how to get it to see my printer?

Comment: Don't have either inkscape snap or printer so can't really answer. try removing the snap, `sudo snap remove inkscape`  ; then reinstall with this option, `sudo snap install --classic inkscape`

Comment: @doug Works like a charm. Write this as an answer so I can mark it answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default snaps are confined to the user's $HOME which can lead to some access issues. In this case it seems more a bug or current limitation of the inkscape snap that it can't access the printer.

So atm the snap can be installed with the `--classic` option to disable confinement.

If snap is already installed then remove

`sudo snap remove inkscape`

Then install with the option

`sudo snap install --classic inkscape`

This option will prove useful with other snaps, particularly media players.

Comment: I ran `snap install --classic vlc` but still, VLC 3.0 as a snap cannot read files from a different partition.  If there is no way to disable confinement, for some application such as VLC where media can reside outside of the application's partition, it is a show stopper.  There are ways to go around with bind mounts, but sure is not user friendly.

Comment: @  Hans DeragonIn,  16.04 & 18.04 there is no longer any need to use --classic, vlc is allowed to browse external volumes. I don't think using --classic with vlc would have any effect either way..

Comment: Doug, my partition is not an external volume.  It is a 2nd partition of my primary hard disk.  And snap does not allow access to them as of 2018-03-25.  See bug report:  [Bug #1620771](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1620771)

Comment: Doesn't matter, as I said vlc works with all mounted volumes in 16.04 & 18.04, if you're using something else you should mention..

Comment: Doug, I do not understand your comment.  I presented you a bug report that states clearly that VLC cannot read files from my 2nd partition on my HDD.  And I confirm that bug; on my 16.04 system, I cannot read files from my 2nd partition on my HDD with VLC installed as a snap.  It is not a matter of opinion, but a fact.

Comment: I have multiple partitions & installs of Ubuntu on the same drive, in both the 16.04 & 18.04 installs a snap vlc can browse  to any other mounted volume & play media. That bug report is old & in this case not relevant. I suggest you start a new question & present fuller info about your install, snapd version,  ect. It works just fine here.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a bug. Snaps run in containers with separate environments which prevent applications to access all the system (as the classic applications do) for security. By default printers are not accessible, but can be enabled with:

```
sudo snap connect inkscape:cups-control :cups-control
```

That will allow printers to show in Inkscape. Change `inskcape` for the name of the application (for example, `gimp`) if needed.
It happened to me with WPS Office: [this was my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083698/wps-office-has-not-found-any-installed-printers).

You need to restart the application to take effect.

In my personal opinion, it would be nice if during installation you could specify such permissions or that the applications could decide which permissions requires and let the user know about them (like Android applications).

Comment: It is a bug however when cups-control doesn't even show up as an available connection. https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1840926

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be a bug. What is a bug is that cups-control doesn't even show up as a connection until you connect to it.

```
ppetraki@vanguard:~/Sandbox/graphics$ snap connections | grep cups
ppetraki@vanguard:~/Sandbox/graphics$ sudo snap connect brave:cups-control  :cups-control
[sudo] password for ppetraki: 
ppetraki@vanguard:~/Sandbox/graphics$ snap connections | grep cups
cups-control              brave:cups-control                         :cups-control                    manual
```

So you can't solve the problem until you know what the solution looks like. I was looking for things like "lpr" or "printer" in the list of available connections to no avail. This is on 18.04.