# WPS Office has not found any installed printers

Tags: printing, cups-lpd, wps-office

Installed WPS Office in two computers (Ubuntu 18.04 x64), one through snap and one though apt. I have a printer connected to another server, which is published using cups, and works fine in other applications (like libreoffice, pdf viewer, etc).

In both the clients, it shows the error: "WPS Office has not found any installed printers" when clicking the print button or from the menu.

I couldn't find any solution so far. Any way to debug this issue or to solve it?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/886488/application-installed-as-snap-package-cant-see-printer/1128182#1128182

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was provided in [a rejected edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/915057) by an anonymous user. I'm posting the proposed solution as it results to be useful:

```
sudo snap connect wps-office:cups-control :cups-control
```

For WPS Office 2019:

```
sudo snap connect wps-2019-snap:cups-control :cups-control
```

**Note:** You can check the name of snap package in `$HOME/snap` folder.

After that, open the application and the printers will be shown as expected.